# PyQt Node interface - Parrent to ItemIsMovable object

Tags: python, pyqt4, draggable, nodes

So I am building a node based interface using PyQt for a project I am working on and I am having some issues getting objects that belong to the base not to follow it in space. I would like when the user drags the base node, the child objects (inputs and output boxes) to follow it. I have a drag-able node that works but the child objects are not following properly. Any ideas?

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
This is the base py file for the GUI
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from array import *


"""
Base class for a node. Contains all the initialization, drawing, and containing inputs and outputs
"""

class node():

    width = 100
    height = 100
    color = 1
    x = 90
    y = 60
    inputs=[]
    outputs=[]


    def __init__(self, nWidth, nHeight):
        self.width = nWidth
        self.height = nHeight
        self.iniNodeData()

    """
    This is where inputs and outputs will be created
    """
    def iniNodeData(self):
        for j in range(5):
            this = self
            x = input(this,90, 0+(j*10))
            self.inputs.append(x)



    """Draw the node then the input and output objects"""
    def draw(self, drawObj):
        item = drawObj.addRect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        item.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        for curInput in self.inputs:
            curInput.draw(drawObj) 
        print("(", self.x, ",", self.y, ")")



"""
Nodes will evaluate from the last node to the first node, therefore inputs are evaluted
"""
class input():
    currentConnectedNode = None
    currentConnectedOutput = None
    parentNode = None
    width = 10
    height = 10
    x = 1
    y = 1
    color = 1

    def __init__(self, pnode, posX, posY):

        self.parentNode = pnode
        self.x = posX
        self.y = posY
        self.color = 1


    def draw(self, drawObj):
        item = drawObj.addRect(self.x+self.parentNode.x, self.y+self.parentNode.y, self.width, self.height)


class output():
    parentNode = None


class MainWindow(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

    nodes = []

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        for j in range(1):
            x = node(100,100)
            self.nodes.append(x)

        self.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene())    
        self.setWindowTitle('RIS RIB Generator')
        self.setGeometry(800, 600, 800, 850)

        self.initNodes()

        self.show()


    def initNodes(self):

        for curNode in self.nodes:
            curNode.draw(self.scene())



def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    app.exec_()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do I need to create some kind of event listener like stated here? http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after a week I figured it out. You need to do a few things.

ensure the flags are correct:

```
    self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
    self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
```

Once those are set you can use the built in event handelers but these over ride the original ones. so from inside your user defined one, you need to call the event handeler from the base class. Example:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, e):
    print("Square got mouse press event")
    print("Event came to us accepted: %s"%(e.isAccepted(),))
    QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.mousePressEvent(self, e)
```

Here is my working example of my progress.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
This is the base py file for the GUI

Todo list
-----------------
- Pop up menu for adding new Nodes
- node connectivity
- create data structure for storing 

"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from array import *

"""
Base class for a node. Contains all the inilization, drawing, and containing inputs and outputs
"""
class node(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem):

    width = 100
    height = 100
    color = 1
    x = 90
    y = 60
    inputs=[]
    outputs=[]
    viewObj = None

    def __init__(self, n_x, n_y, n_width,n_height):
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, n_x, n_y, n_width, n_height)
        self.width = n_width
        self.height = n_height
        self.x = n_x
        self.y = n_y
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.iniNodeData()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print("Square got mouse press event")
        print("Event came to us accepted: %s"%(e.isAccepted(),))
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.mousePressEvent(self, e)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        print("Square got mouse release event")
        print("Event came to us accepted: %s"%(e.isAccepted(),))
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, e)

    """
    This is where inputs and outputs will be created based on node type
    """ 
    def iniNodeData(self):
        print('making node data')
        for j in range(5):
            this = self
            x = input(this,0, 0+(j*10))
            self.inputs.append(x)

        for k in range(5):
            this = self
            x = output(this,self.x+self.width, self.y+(k*10))
            self.outputs.append(x)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print('Dragging@')
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        print('moving!')

"""
Nodes will evaluate from the last node to the first node, therefore inputs are evaluted
"""
class input(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem):
    currentConnectedNode = None
    currentConnectedOutput = None
    parentNode = None
    width = 10
    height = 10
    x = 1
    y = 1
    color = 1
    drawItem = None

    def __init__(self, pnode, posX, posY):
        self.parentNode = pnode
        self.x = posX
        self.y = posY
        self.color = 1
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, self.x+self.parentNode.x, self.y+self.parentNode.y, self.width, self.height, self.parentNode)



'''
Output value from a node
'''
class output(node):
    parentNode = None
    width = 10
    height = 10
    x = 1
    y = 1

    def __init__(self, pnode, posX, posY):
        self.parentNode = pnode
        self.x = posX
        self.y = posY
        self.color = 1
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, self.x-self.width, self.y, self.width, self.height, self.parentNode)


'''
Check Click events on the scene Object
'''
class Scene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):


    nodes = []

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print("Scene got mouse press event")
        print("Event came to us accepted: %s"%(e.isAccepted(),))
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.mousePressEvent(self, e)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        print("Scene got mouse release event")
        print("Event came to us accepted: %s"%(e.isAccepted(),))
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.mouseReleaseEvent(self, e)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        print('Scene got drag move event')

    def addNode(self):
        newNode = self.addItem(node(250,250,100,150))
        self.nodes.append(newNode)


'''
Main Window Object
'''

class MainWindowUi(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('RIS RIB Generator')
        self.scene = Scene(0, 0, 800, 850, self)
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)


        exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        newNodeAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit24.png'), 'New Node', self)
        newNodeAction.setStatusTip('Add a blank node')
        newNodeAction.triggered.connect(self.scene.addNode)


        self.statusBar()
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(newNodeAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)


'''
Start Point
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindowUi()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```